# xrandr: cannot find output "eDP-1"

Tags: display, monitor

I am trying to add some missing displays in ubuntu 16.04 system, I followed the following site for configuration:

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/04/custom-screen-resolution-ubuntu-desktop/

```
dev@mysite-dev:~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
VGA-1 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768      60.00* 
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   848x480       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
dev@mysite-dev:~$ cvt 1920 1080
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
dev@mysite-dev:~$ sudo xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
[sudo] password for dev: 
dev@mysite-dev:~$ sudo xrandr --addmode eDP-1 "1920x1080_60.00"
xrandr: cannot find output "eDP-1"
dev@mysite-dev:~$
```

As you can see I am getting the following error:

```
xrandr: cannot find output "eDP-1"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It failed because your output display is isn't called `eDP-1`, you need to replace it with the one you're using.

```
sudo xrandr --addmode `xrandr | grep -e " connected [^(]" | sed -e "s/\([A-Z0-9]\+\) connected.*/\1/"` "1920x1080_60.00"
```

The command will output your currently connected display, in my case it was `LVDS-1`

```
:~$ xrandr | grep -e " connected [^(]" | sed -e "s/\([A-Z0-9]\+\) connected.*/\1/"
LVDS-1
```

Comment: `xrandr | grep -e " connected [^(]" | cut "-d " -f1` is a wee bit shorter ;-)